# see Ethereum USD value at time of transaction?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, bitcoin, price, blockchain.info

on Blockchain.info, when you hover over the value of a transaction, it will actually tell you the value of Bitcoin in USD at the time of that transaction (as well as how much that is worth now)

is there any platform or website for this in Ethereum?

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Etherscan](https://etherscan.io) does this. For example, here's a random old transaction:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x135ba7f5b2ffd81b0dbb3483716e87e5f8d374b2736f3d24967962893bc827fb

By default, it shows the value in USD based on the current Ethereum price, but if you click on the dollar amount, it switches to the USD value at the time of the transaction.